# Touchpad ASUS E403N no longer responds

Tags: touchpad

I use Lubuntu on an asus E403N, the touchpad no longer responds to the standby release, I have to reboot to find it. I tried without success:

```
`sudo modprobe -r psmouse


sudo modprobe psmouse

xinput disable 'ELAN1200:00 04F3:303E Touchpad' && xinput enable 'ELAN1200:00 04F3:303E Touchpad

~$ xinput 

⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1200:00 04F3:303E Touchpad            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1200:00 04F3:303E Mouse               id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse           id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Camera: USB Camera                    id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

5.15.0-52-generic

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please explain what stand by release is.

Comment: suspend, not hibernation. Same problem with releases 22.04 and 22.10, Ubuntu, Xubuntu and Lubuntu. Sorry about my rough English

Comment: suspend when I raise the lid of the netbook.